# React Native api doesn't work on physical Android device (Error: Network Error)

Tags: android, xmlhttprequest, axios, react-native

My api doesn't work on physical device Android, I checked other api, they work, only mine does not work. Everything works on the emulator.

debugging code:

```
>GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest = GLOBAL.originalXMLHttpRequest || GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest;
```

to code, `api` starts working, although the data comes already an object and not json.

How can I make this api work correctly on my physical device, or using this command for debugging might be the right solution?
I'm using axios for making api request

Code :

```
 const data = await axios
      .get(`https://MY_API`, {
        headers: {
          Host: 'MY_API',
          Accept: '*/*',
          'User-Agent':
            'myApp/7.6.2 (iPhone; iOS 12.4.5; Scale/2.00)',
          'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
          'Accept-Language': 'en-US;q=1, ru-RU;q=0.9',
          Connection: 'close',
        },
      })
      .then(books => {

        (logic)

      })
      .catch(err => {


        console.log(err);

      });
```

My error:

```
Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at EventTarget.handleError (xhr.js:83)
    at EventTarget.dispatchEvent (event-target-shim.js:818)
    at EventTarget.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:575)
    at EventTarget.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:389)
    at XMLHttpRequest.js:502
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:189)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:425)
    at MessageQueue.js:112
    at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:373)
```

P.C Sorry for my bad English ;)

Comment: are you making http or https request ,maybe you should right android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in mafifest

Comment: https.
i set 
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" ,
android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" ,
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
in src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
but it did not help

Comment: any solution you found?

Comment: I get the same error on the emulator.